# Nginx set let's encrypt SSL for port 80 and port 8000

Tags: nginx, devops, digital-ocean

I am using ***Lets Encrypt Certbot*** to generate free SSL and everything works fine.

I am setting `port 80` for Front-End and `port 8000` for Back-End.

### Problem is:

The SSL just work for `PORT 80` only and her is my NGinx config file code.

### Front-End port 80 code:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/front-end;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name tradekeyegypt.tk www.tradekeyegypt.tk;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tradekeyegypt.tk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tradekeyegypt.tk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

### Back-end Port 8000 Code:

```
server {

    listen 8000 default_server;
    listen [::]:8000 default_server;


    root /var/www/html/back-end/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

 location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you create subdomain and run that ssl on that?

Comment: Can you recommend an article for that?

Comment: Which vps are you using for server?

Comment: I am using DigitalOcean Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 0):

Do this on you backend configuration file

```
server {

listen 80;
listen [::]:8000 80;


root /var/www/html/back-end/public;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name subdomain.tradekeyegypt.tk www.subdomain.tradekeyegypt.tk;



location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

  location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

 }
```

After this run service nginx restart

After making backend configuration file that . Add a name record for that subdomain in the server in the digitalocean backend .

If you can open the subdomain url on the browser after this . For certbot run

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Now certbot will also read the subdomain

Answer (score 0):

The SSL works on port 443 and not on port 80, which process HTTP requests (and not HTTPS).

Also, certbot doesn't support ports different than 443, which means you should use the same port (443) for both your client and server.

In this case, you can differentiate the requests between the client and the server by their path, something like `/api` or `/server`.

You should change the server config to something like this:

```
location /server/ {
            rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8000;
             ...
    }
```

Remember to change the code in your client to send requests to the new server address.

Hope that helps.